# Sharepoint top link bar visible true/false

Tags: sharepoint-2010

All,

I have a default top link bar in sharepoint which we keep on adding/modifying.

We have a requirement as such that few links, we want to make visible true/false based on user permission.

Is it possible through sharepoint settings? or we need to handle it throuhg code?

we are using SP2010.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First make sure to enable the Publishing feature of your site. You can do this by following the steps [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/enable-publishing-features-HA010157772.aspx).

Once that is done you can use Security Trimming and Audience Targeting for your top link bar. Steps on how to do it can be found [here](http://sharepointyankee.com/tag/top-link-bar/). Please take note however that this may lead to performance issues once your SharePoint site grows. There are other suggestions in the linked site above on how to address these issues as well.